# Is there anything like "displaystyle" for "arrays"?

Tags: math-mode, arrays, displaystyle

I have this equation and I would like to "get more space" into it, how to do it?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\vnull}{\boldsymbol{0}}
\newcommand{\vK}{\boldsymbol{K}}
\newcommand{\vN}{\boldsymbol{N}}
\newcommand{\vT}{\boldsymbol{T}}
\newcommand{\vD}{\boldsymbol{D}}
\begin{equation*}
  \left(
    \begin{array}{l|l|l}
      \vK & \vN^\top & \vT^\top \\
      \hline
      - \rho \vD(\mathcal{A}_\nu) \vN & \vD(\mathcal{I}_\nu) & \vnull\\
      \hline
      - \rho \vD(\mathcal{A}_t) \vT & \vnull
                     & \vD(\mathcal{I}_t^+ \cup \mathcal{I}_t^-)
    \end{array}
  \right)
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Define a `\bigstrut` and add it to each line.  I realize one can also do something like `\renewcommand\arraystretch{3}` instead of `\bigstrut`, but I do not like the asymmetric vertical look that it produces when `\hline`s are involved.  With `\bigstrut`, you can fully control the space.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\def\bigstrut{\rule[-1ex]{0pt}{3.5ex}}
\begin{document}

\newcommand{\vnull}{\boldsymbol{0}}
\newcommand{\vK}{\boldsymbol{K}}
\newcommand{\vN}{\boldsymbol{N}}
\newcommand{\vT}{\boldsymbol{T}}
\newcommand{\vD}{\boldsymbol{D}}
\begin{equation*}
  \left(
    \begin{array}{l|l|l}
      \bigstrut\vK & \vN^\top & \vT^\top \\
      \hline
      - \bigstrut\rho \vD(\mathcal{A}_\nu) \vN & \vD(\mathcal{I}_\nu) & \vnull\\
      \hline
      - \bigstrut\rho \vD(\mathcal{A}_t) \vT & \vnull
                     & \vD(\mathcal{I}_t^+ \cup \mathcal{I}_t^-)
    \end{array}
  \right)
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

or if `\def\bigstrut{\rule[-2ex]{0pt}{5ex}}`, then

[image]

For comparison here is the result of using `\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.8}` with no `\bigstrut` added.  I don't like it as much:

[image]